# how to sort a list using flask with mongodb?

Tags: flask

I'm printing this list in flask but I wanted it to be sorted after username like username begins with A first then username with B then C and so on, how can I do that. I'm not sure if I should implement that in .html file or in another file but I've put the code of the list in .html file, I can gladly show other files if wanted

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr><td>{{ user.username }}</td><td>{{ user.lastname }}</td><td>{{ user.vorname }}</td><td>{{ user.birthdate }}</td><td>{{ user.email }}</td><td> <a href="/users/edit?id={{user.pk}}">edit</a> </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in template - Jinjas philosophy is to leave more complex login in Flask, so you can od this before passing `users` to template.

I would sort with:

```py
from unidecode import unidecode
 
users.sort(key=lambda x: unidecode(x.username.lower()))
```

This should solve problems with upper/lower letter, as well as special characters (using for Czech alphabet).

simpler way:

```
users.sort(key=lambda x: x.username)
```